# Как вызвать боковую шторку без тулбара

Tags: android-navigation-drawer, collapsing-toolbar-layout

Как реализовать вызов NavigationDrawer без тулбара. Т.е. в левом верхнем меню нужна просто круглая кнопка. На заднем фоне будет навигационная карта и я не хочу чтобы тулбар закрывал собой её часть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повесьте на кнопку обработчик `onClick`, а в нём используйте метод `openDrawer`.

```
private DrawerLayout drawer;
. . .
drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
shtorka = findViewById(R.id.shtorka);
. . .
// В onClick
drawer.openDrawer(shtorka);
```

Если шторка работает на `DrawerLayout`, это должно сработать.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!